# Penetration testing framework for Windows Desktop applications

Tags: appsec, debugging

Is there a burpsuite-like framework for Windows Desktop applications? I.e. I'm looking for something that would allow me to intercept user-input data sent to my application for manipulation to test specific payloads. I'm assuming this would be debugging related (like in Visual Studio). Is VS the best approach? Or is there something better, specifically designed for pentesting/hacking?